# Add border colour to UIButton Bezeir path

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

UIButton corners only two sides i.e. top right and bottom right with following:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:_nearmeButton.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
_nearmeButton.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

But how to give border colour to above UIButton same as given image [image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Instead of setting your path as a mask you can add it to the buttons layer. Basically (more or less) every UIView is backed by a CALayer. Just set the colors you want on the stroke and the fill and add it to the buttons layer, and you are done.

```
UIBezierPath *borderPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:_nearmeButton.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0)];

CAShapeLayer *borderLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
borderLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
borderLayer.path  = borderPath.CGPath;
borderLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
borderLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
borderLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;
[_nearmeButton.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
```

If your buttons size changes you need to update the layer size also.

Comment: This is in the case, if we want the corners on 4 sides, but I need corner only on 2 sides and border on all sides.